# Forces that are invariant under Galilean spacetime rescaling $\mathbf x' = \lambda \mathbf x$, $t' = \lambda^2 t$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity, invariants

Consider a force of the form
$$
m \ddot{\mathbf x}(t) = -k\frac{\mathbf x(t) - \mathbf x_0}{|\mathbf x(t) - \mathbf x_0|^d}.
$$
For what values of $d$ is this force invariant under the Galilean spacetime rescaling $\mathbf x' = \lambda \mathbf x$, $t' = \lambda^2 t$? What does it mean to be invariant in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force is:
$$F=-k\frac{x(t)-x_0}{|x(t)-x(0)|^d}\tag 1$$

Invariant mean that the transformed force has this "structure"

$$F'=-k\frac{x'(t')-x'_0}{|x'(t)-x'(0)|^d}\tag 2$$

with

$$x(t)\mapsto \frac 1\lambda\,x'(t/\lambda^2)\quad,t'=t/\lambda^2 $$

in Eq. (1):

$$F'=-\frac{k}{\lambda}\frac{\left((x'(t')-x'(0)\right)}
{\left(\frac 1\lambda\left(x'(t')-x'(0)\right)\right)^d}$$

thus for $~d=1~$ Eq. (1) and (2) have the same "structure"